# List in lists in jinja2 template

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I have the following variables defined:

```
datasources:
  - { name: 'dsname', target: ['server1', 'server2'] }
```

Running the following playbook:

```
---
- name: Create file
  template: src="datasource.py" dest="/tmp/datasource.py"
```

The Jinja template i am trying to build from is the following:

```
{% for ds_target in datasources.target 
%} Target:{{ ds_target }} {%
endfor %}
```

How can I do the template to have the following output?

```
Target:server1 Target:server2
```

Any tip would be highly appreciated

Comment: `target: 'server1, 'server2'` this syntax is invalid – please fix quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.
I need help how to make it work, I need list in list to be parsed in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added another loop to go over the list "target", so my code looks something like this:

```
{% for datasource in datasources 
%} {% for dst in datasource.target %}Target:{{ dst }} {% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

Thank you very much guys !

Answer (score 1):

Surely you need to loop over `datasources` itself and then access `target` in each iteration:

```
{% for ds in datasources %} Target:{{ ds.target }} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Excuse me i made a mistake, the datasources.target variable is corrected as above " target: 'server1, 'server2' "

Comment: I want to loop in "datasources.target" eg. for each server in the list "target"

Answer (score 0):

If your question is *"how should I define my `target` list to make my template work?"*, then the answer is:

```
datasources:
  - name: dsname
    target:
      - server1
      - server2
```

or in other notation:

```
datasources:
  - { name: 'dsname', target: ['server1', 'server2'] }
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, doing it like so has the following output:
Target:[u'server1, server2']

Comment: @VeselinHristov if you have this output, you have incorrect quotation. Please copy/paste from my answer. Note, that the first notation has no quotes, so less prone to this errors.

Comment: You are right @KonstantiSuvorov, targets var should be: ['server1', 'server2']